# Java - Compare Two List of String if they have common value and return the how many item is the same

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to compare two List and check if they have in common.

Example

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("id1");
list1.add("id2");
list1.add("id3");
list1.add("id10");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add("id10");
list2.add("id20");
list2.add("id3");
list2.add("id30");
list2.add("id31");
```

and return how many item is having a same value in most shortest and optimal process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is, put the elements in the two lists into a `Set`, check if the `set.size()` is same as `list1.size()+list2.size()`

The diff would be the count of duplicated elements.

Comment: Im not familiar with Set can you please give a complete example of it? Also what access time do I get for this O(1)?

Comment: read java doc `Set`. it is not `O(1)` btw,  internally, java (the `Set.addAll()` method) created a hashmap, and put all elements in it.

Comment: They say that at first while putting elements inside of Set it is O(n) access time then after that any action that will perform with Set is O(1) is it true?

Comment: @ArcherEmiya if you say **any actions**, I am not sure what do you mean by that. Hashtable/map has O(1) for  add/remove/contains actions.

Comment: Thanks again your answers help me a lot!

Comment: a that's wrong write in hash set is O(1) as contains ,remove and size but getting the intersection will be be O(n)

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec I didn't say getting intersection is `O(1)`, I said it is **not** O(1) ;-)

Comment: sry i typed my answer before yours appear^^ i amm totaly aggree with you ^^

Comment: Thanks @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
ArrayList intersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
intersection.retainAll(list2);
```

intersection will contain the common elements

Comment: retainAll doesn't allow null element. also it is slower than creating a hashMap. OP asked "most shortest and optimal process"

Comment: To me this seems short and good. The question wisely didn’t ask for “fast”.

Comment: @OleV.V. fair enough, we have different understanding on `optimal`

Comment: personnaly in its case to have an optimal way i ll use hashSet since the beginning  and then i could use std methods

Comment: he is serching for something in O(1) but in my sence its impossible the better he will found will be somthing like O(list1.size()+list2.size())

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the most efficient way to do it but i would do something like this:

```
public static int getCommonValues() {
    int values = 0;
    if(list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        Iterator it = list1.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            String value = it.next();

            Iterator it2 = list2.iterator();
            while(it2.hasNext()) {
                String value2 = it2.next();

                if(value2 == value) {
                    values = values + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using following code:

```
    Set<String> set =  new HashSet<>(list1);
    set.addAll(list2);
    System.out.println(((list1.size() + list2.size()) - set.size()));
```

Comment: What access time do I get for this, O(n)?

Comment: what is your n ?

Comment: @ArcherEmiya this answer is actually the codes implementation of my answer. Your problem has no `O(1)` solution, if you are looking for one.

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec n = number of items in list